# How to trigger a write event?

Tags: python, python-2.4, asyncore

I know there is a 'writable' interface to indicate there is data to be written. But once the `asyncore` loop enters sleep, when no data to write, there is no chance to wake it up till timeout.

This means that the data can't be sent in real time.

I tried to change the 'writable' method to always return `True`, but this resulted in HIGH CPU usage.

Isn't there any solution to trigger a write event in real time?

BTW: I'm using python 2.4.3

Comment: Python 2.4? Sweet Mother of God. So you are the one still using it. ;)

Comment: We're using RedHat Enterprise u5 and 2.4.3 is the only choice for me...